# Counting groups of 3? Possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that is selecting groups of entries of 3 that match and don't exist in the second table.

I need to find a way to return via 'count_result' the count of the number of groups found, not individual entry ids as below.

How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT COUNT(sub.entry_id) as count_result
FROM exp_submissions AS sub
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud1 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_1
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud2 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_2
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud3 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_3
WHERE jud1.entry_id_1 IS NULL
AND jud2.entry_id_2 IS NULL
AND jud3.entry_id_3 IS NULL
AND sub.member_group = 6
AND sub.type_id = 1
GROUP BY sub.member_id, sub.portfolio_number
HAVING count(sub.portfolio_number) = 3
```

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output?

Comment: How about `WHERE NOT EXISTS () AND NOT EXISTS() AND NOT EXISTS()`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No subquery necessary.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(sub.member_id, sub.portfolio_number)) as count_result
FROM exp_submissions AS sub
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud1 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_1
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud2 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_2
LEFT JOIN exp_judging_portfolios AS jud3 ON sub.entry_id = jud1.entry_id_3
WHERE jud1.entry_id_1 IS NULL
AND jud2.entry_id_2 IS NULL
AND jud3.entry_id_3 IS NULL
AND sub.member_group = 6
AND sub.type_id = 1
GROUP BY sub.member_id, sub.portfolio_number
HAVING count(sub.portfolio_number) = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(sub.member_id, '-', sub.portfolio_number))` instead.

Comment: Perfect. The only problem is if it returns no results, instead of the counting being 0, it just doesn't return anything. How can I return 0?

Comment: Try wrapping the `COUNT` in `IFNULL( COUNT(...), 0)`

Comment: Still nothing. Do you know of any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you make a SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some sample data to test with?

Answer (score 0):

Use your query as the source for another query that just counts the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
      -- YOUR QUERY GOES HERE --
) AS t
```